# Counting with Recurrence, Strings with 1 and 2 . Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Let T(n) be the set of all strings of 1's and 2's that add up to n. For example: 21221 2 T(8) because it is a string of 1's and 2's that add up to 8.

Show that |T(0)| = 1 and |T(1)| = 1 and by using a combinatorial argument, show that |T(n)| = |T(n - 1)| + |T(n - 2)|.

Given solution:

(This shows that |T(n)| is the Fibonacci numbers!)

T(0) = {Ø}, T(1) = {1} so |T(0)| = 1 and |T(1)| = 1. Then T(n) can be split up into the strings that start with 1 and the strings that start with 2. There are T(n- 1) strings that start with 1 because the remaining characters in the string make up a string of 1's and 2's that add up to (n-1). Similarly, the number of strings that start with 2 is T(n - 2) because the remaining characters in the string make up a string of 1's and 2's that add up to 2.

Sorry for my poor english skill and for asking this stupid question. This solution seems to explain why the number of strings that start with 2 is T(n-2). however I am not able to follow it because to me. Either the string starts with 1 or 2, it only take up a single digit. so it should just T(n-1) to me. Please help me understand the solution better. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The $n$ does not stand for the number of digits, but for the sum of the digits. Accordingly, $|T(n)|$ stands for the number of strings whose digits add up to $n$.

If a string starts with a $2$, then after the $2$ you should get a string whose digits add up to $n-2$, and there are $|T(n-2)|$ such strings.